# Multiple value same id into single line in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, string-aggregation

Here is my table i want to add value in one line format my code is

```
OrderDate OrderID ItemNo PaymentType        Cash    Nets    Visa    AMEX MasterCard Voucher Remarks ReciptNo

2018-01-27  809   40149  Mix Payment Type   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    55.00   NULL    NULL
2018-01-27  809   40149  Mix Payment Type   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    10.00   NULL    NULL    ABC123
2018-01-27  809   40149  Mix Payment Type   NULL    NULL    NULL    4.00    NULL    NULL    NULL    PQE789
2018-01-27  809   40149  Mix Payment Type   NULL    NULL    10.00   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    123456
2018-01-27  809   40149  Mix Payment Type   20.00   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

i want o/p like

```
OrderDate   OrderID     ItemNo       PaymentType        Cash    Nets    Visa    AMEX    MasterCard  Voucher Remarks    ReciptNo
2018-01-27  809         40149        Mix Payment Type   20.00   NULL    10.00   4.00    10.00       55.00   NULL    ABC123,PQR789,123456
```

what should i do for that in sql query

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
SELECT OrderDate,
       OrderID,
       ItemNo,
       PaymentType,
       MAX(Cash),
       MAX(Nets),
       MAX(Visa),
       MAX(AMEX),
       MAX(MasterCard),
       MAX(Voucher),
       MAX(Remarks),
       STUFF((
            SELECT ', ' + ISNULL(R2.ReciptNo,'')
            FROM TableName t2
            WHERE t1.OrderID= t2.OrderID
            FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '') AS ReciptNos
FROM TableName t1
GROUP BY OrderDate,OrderID,ItemNo,PaymentType
```

Comment: You need to call the `.value` method on the XML you have created, otherwise you get an error saying that data type XML is not valid for the stuff function. - e.g. `FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value ('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2...`.

Comment: i will try let check me thank you your valuable time and answer  Jaydip Jadhav sir

Comment: @Jaydip Jadhav it's working fine thank you so much ..........

Answer (score 1):

As you want only one column with the same values, you could go with a group by approach:

```
SELECT
  OrderDate, OrderID, ItemNo, PaymentType,
  MAX(cash), MAX(nets), MAX(Visa), MAX(AMEX), MAX(MasterCard), MAX(Voucher),
  STRING_AGG(Remarks, ', '), STRING_AGG(ReciptNo, ', ')
FROM myTable
GROUP BY OrderDate, OrderID, ItemNo, PaymentType
```

This obviously only works if you have no two rows both having for example a Cash entry.

PS: A [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9ec32/4) for playing around.

Comment: `STRING_AGG` is new to SQL Server 2017 - and won't work with SQL Server 2012 (which the question is tagged with).

Answer (score 0):

You could try

1. to group this on ItemNo to get single line
2. use MAX(Cash) and etc to get the only not null value